# How to skip last n rows with simple_html_dom or Dom Document?

Tags: php, html-table, html-parsing, simple-html-dom, skip

Is there a way to skip always the last n rows of a parsed table via simple_html_dom or dom document?

I tried to work with fixed rownumbers, but since the source file could change its amount of rows, it didn't work out.

This is my standard code for parsing a table. Do you have an idea or hint for me, how to skip always last two rows?

```
$table = $html->find('table', 1);
$rowData = array();

    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        // initialize array to store the cell data from each row

    $roster = array();
        foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        $roster[] = $cell->innertext;
    }
    foreach($row->find('th') as $cell) {
        $roster[] = $cell->innertext;
    }
        $rowData[] = $roster;
    }

        foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($tr as $td)
            echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table></td><td>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [`pop`](http://php.net/array_pop) two items from your array of `find` results:

```
$rows = $table->find('tr');
array_pop($rows);
array_pop($rows);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Sure, it's not an ideal solution, as an alternative you can get `count` of found rows and use index to control current element in `foreach`:

```
$rows = $table->find('tr');
$limit = count($rows) - 2;
$counter = 0;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($counter++ < $limit) {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Used `array_pop` and it delivered as wished. How would it work vice versa? Lets say I want to show only last two rows and skip all before.

Comment: Use a counter as in second example. __Or__ `array_pop` returns you popped elements, so you can `pop` them and output.